# How to get all the jobs, steps, status, duration Of a particular day in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have to get all the Steps in every Job in the same order of steps as they are scheduled along with some more data **On a particular day**, like below:

**JobName, StepName, LastRunDate, LastRunDuration, LastRunStatus, LastRunStatusMsg**

What I have currently with gives me what I want, BUT it doesn't give me all the Steps. Sometimes it gives me all the Jobs with all the steps, sometimes only few jobs.

Here is my Query:

```
SELECT  JobName ,
        StepName ,
        LastRunDateTime ,
        [LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)] ,
        LastRunStatus ,
        LastRunStatusMsg
FROM    ( SELECT    j.name AS JobName ,
                    s.step_name AS StepName ,
                    s.step_id ,
                    LastRunDateTime = msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(CASE
                                                              WHEN s.last_run_date = 0
                                                              THEN NULL
                                                              ELSE s.last_run_date
                                                              END,
                                                              CASE
                                                              WHEN s.last_run_time = 0
                                                              THEN NULL
                                                              ELSE s.last_run_time
                                                              END) ,
                    STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000'
                            + CAST(s.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),
                            6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') AS 'LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)' ,
                    CASE s.last_run_outcome
                      WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
                      WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
                      WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
                      WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
                      WHEN 4 THEN 'Running' -- In Progress
                    END AS LastRunStatus ,
                    REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(h.message, CHAR(9), ''),
                                            CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(12), ''),
                            CHAR(13), '') AS LastRunStatusMsg
          FROM      sysjobs j
                    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s ON j.job_id = s.job_id
                    JOIN sysjobhistory h ON s.job_id = h.job_id
                                            AND s.step_id = h.step_id
                                            AND s.last_run_date = h.run_date
                                            AND s.last_run_time = h.run_time
        ) MainQ
WHERE   CONVERT(DATE, MainQ.LastRunDateTime) = CONVERT(DATE, '06/16/2015')
ORDER BY MainQ.JobName , MainQ.LastRunDateTime
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved like this:

```
select 
jt.JOBTYPE As JobType,
j.name As JobName,
s.step_name As StepName,
msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time) As RunDateTime,
STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT('000000' + CAST(s.last_run_duration AS VARCHAR(6)),  6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':')
AS 'LastRunDuration (HH:MM:SS)',
CASE s.last_run_outcome
WHEN 0 THEN 'Failed'
WHEN 1 THEN 'Succeeded'
WHEN 2 THEN 'Retry'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Canceled'
WHEN 4 THEN 'Running' -- In Progress
END AS LastRunStatus,
Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(h.message, Char(9), ''), Char(10), ''), Char(12), ''), Char(13), '') As LastRunStatusMsg
From msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps s
ON j.job_id = s.job_id
INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory h
ON s.job_id = h.job_id 
AND s.step_id = h.step_id 
AND h.step_id <> 0
and Convert(Date, msdb.dbo.agent_datetime(run_date, run_time)) = CONVERT(Date, GETDATE())
Left JOIN BASE..JOB_TYPE jt
ON j.name=jt.JOBNAME
where j.enabled = 1   --Only Enabled Jobs
```